# How to push a mysql result's fields up to become the property of a class

Tags: php, mysql, datamapper, service-layer

How can I push a mysql result result's fields up to become the property of a class?

For instance, this is my result,

```
   object(ArticleModel)[4]
      public 'item' => 
        object(stdClass)[7]
          public 'article_id' => string '4' (length=1)
          public 'parent_id' => string '4' (length=1)
          public 'template_id' => string '4' (length=1)
          public 'type' => string 'page' (length=4)
          public 'url' => string 'home' (length=4)
          public 'title' => string 'Home' (length=4)
          ... and so on...
```

I want it to be like this,

```
object(stdClass)[7]
  public 'article_id' => string '4' (length=1)
  public 'parent_id' => string '4' (length=1)
  public 'template_id' => string '4' (length=1)
  public 'type' => string 'page' (length=4)
  public 'url' => string 'home' (length=4)
  public 'title' => string 'Home' (length=4)
  ... and so on...
```

Model, Mapper, Service below are the classes how I get to the result above (
    `object(ArticleModel)[4]public 'item' => [...]`
).

model,

```
class ArticleModel
{
    // It is not ideal if I have to set the property manually.
    public $article_id;
    public $title;
    public $url; 
    ... and so on...
}
```

mapper,

```
class ArticleMapper
{
    private $Database;

    public function __construct(Database $pdo)
    {
        $this->Database = $pdo;
    }

    public function getRow($article_id)
    {
        $sql = "
            SELECT *
            FROM article AS p
            WHERE article_id = ?
        ";

        $this->item = $this->Database->fetchRowObject($sql, $article_id);

        return $this;
    }

    public function addContent()
    {
        ...
    }

    public function mapRow(ArticleModel $ArticleModel, $article_id)
    {
       $ArticleModel->item = $this->getRow($article_id)->item;
    }
}
```

service,

```
class ArticleService
{
    public function __construct(Database $pdo)
    {
        $this->Database = $pdo;
    }

    public function fetchRow($article_id)
    {
        $ArticleModel = new ArticleModel();
        $ArticleMapper = new ArticleMapper($this->Database);
        $ArticleMapper->mapRow($ArticleModel,$article_id);
        return $ArticleModel;
    }
}
```

view/ controller,

```
// Instance of Database.
$Database = new Database(DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASS);

// Make connection.
$Database->connect();

$ArticleService = new ArticleService($Database);
$article = $ArticleService->fetchRow(4);

var_dump($article);
```

result,

```
object(ArticleModel)[4]
  public 'item' => 
    object(stdClass)[7]
      public 'article_id' => string '4' (length=1)
      public 'parent_id' => string '4' (length=1)
      public 'template_id' => string '4' (length=1)
      public 'type' => string 'page' (length=4)
      public 'url' => string 'home' (length=4)
      public 'title' => string 'Home' (length=4)
      ... and so on...
```

I am following this [slideshare example](http://www.slideshare.net/aaronsaray/enterprise-php-mappers-models-and-services) to make my example above.

Comment: What do you think this line does? `$ArticleModel->item = $this->getRow($article_id)->item;` .. also, your objects are leaking encapsulation.

Comment: it makes this `object(ArticleModel)[4]public 'item' => [...]` of course.

Comment: $array[4]['item'][7] i think should bring up that result else try to make a function that seperates the arrays and merges them then unsets the unnecessary other than that try fetch_assoc parameter in your pdo extend